# "use strict" in the middle of the program

Tags: javascript, strict, use-strict

Why the second function didn't use the **"use strict";** mode (*it shows me window object in console*):

```
function test() {
    console.log(this);
}
test();   // will be global or window, it's okay

"use strict";

function test2() {
    console.log(this);
}
test2(); // will be global, BUT WHY? It must be undefined, because I have used strict mode!
```

But if I define strict mode **in the body** of the second function, all will be as I expect.

```
function test() {
    console.log(this);
}
test();   // will be global or window

function test2() {
"use strict";
    console.log(this);
}
test2();
```

My question is simple — why it happens?

Comment: In order to have an effect, `"use strict";` has to be at the very top of a code block or function. If any code is before it, it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

> To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the exact statement "use strict"; (or 'use strict';) before any other statements.

and

> Likewise, to invoke strict mode for a function, put the exact statement "use strict"; (or 'use strict';) in the function's body before any other statements.

In your first code block, you have `"use strict";` but it isn't the *first* statement in the script, so it has no effect.

In your second, it is the first statement in a function, so it does.

Comment: would something like `function myFunc(){} 'use strict'; function myOtherFunc() { // my first expressions }` work?

Answer (score 2):

Because `"use strict"` only has effects if it's the first statement of the current script/function. From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) :

> To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the exact statement `"use strict";` (or `'use strict';`) **before any other statements**
>
> Likewise, to invoke strict mode for a function, put the exact statement `"use strict";` (or `'use strict';`) in the function's body **before any other statements.**